# raspberry Pi and processing problem with Camera Capture

Tags: raspbian, video, webcam, streaming-video, java

I installed Processing 2.2.1 (linux) on the RasPi (running Debian Wheezy) to connect a USB-Webcam and capture video stream with the standart processing.video* library. When I try to run the program (from processing window or exported) I get the following error:

**NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native**

After searching the web for several days I found and tried following solutions, wich did not change anything:

- Install gStreamer 0.10 package  (as seen [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/1353/raspberry-pi-gstreamer-video/p1))
- Update to the latest Java Version which is:
  *java version "1.8.0-ea" 

  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108) 

  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)*
- install JNA 4.0.0 (reference [here](http://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1086))

after it still resulting in the same error, I am not really shure what to try next since I am also more or less a beginner when it comes to the RaspberryPi and Java.

Any Tips/Hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use a USB camera and don't use Java on a rpi.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine some other combinations that should work much better, but the problem is I am not familar with python neither with C++. This is part of a project in university, so I also have not much time to get into that other stuff, and with a solution to that error I think it would work fine for my needs..